# Getting DEADLINE_EXCEEDED on a Flink Job while using GCP PubSub source

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, google-cloud-pubsub

The below error keeps repeating every 15s while using a Pub/Sub Source for the Flink Job that I'm using.  https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/datastream/pubsub/

```
Source: pub-sub-source -> filter -> (Sink: Docstore Sink, Map -> Sink: pinot-kafka-sink) (2/2)#3 (b7790c8ab117377fb8d85b1af23b1d11) switched from RUNNING to FAILED.
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: deadline exceeded after 14.999620292s. [remote_addr=pubsub.googleapis.com/123.123.12.12:443]
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:262)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:243)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:156)
    at com.google.pubsub.v1.SubscriberGrpc$SubscriberBlockingStub.pull(SubscriberGrpc.java:1641)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.gcp.pubsub.BlockingGrpcPubSubSubscriber.pull(BlockingGrpcPubSubSubscriber.java:73)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.gcp.pubsub.BlockingGrpcPubSubSubscriber.pull(BlockingGrpcPubSubSubscriber.java:77)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.gcp.pubsub.BlockingGrpcPubSubSubscriber.pull(BlockingGrpcPubSubSubscriber.java:77)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.gcp.pubsub.BlockingGrpcPubSubSubscriber.pull(BlockingGrpcPubSubSubscriber.java:77)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.gcp.pubsub.BlockingGrpcPubSubSubscriber.pull(BlockingGrpcPubSubSubscriber.java:67)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.gcp.pubsub.PubSubSource.run(PubSubSource.java:128)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:110)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:66)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask$LegacySourceFunctionThread.run(SourceStreamTask.java:267)
```

The PubSubSource that I'm creating looks like the below:

```
PubSubSource pubSubSource =
        PubSubSource.newBuilder()
            .withDeserializationSchema(new SomeDeserializer())
            .withProjectName("some-project")
            .withSubscriptionName("some-subscription")
            .withCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(file))
            .build();
```

Is there any config I need to set so that this doesn't come when there are no messages available in the Pub/Sub subscription ?

I have modified the checkpoint interval to be less than the acknowledgement deadline on Pub/Sub subscription. Still this happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The deadline you are encountering seems to be the `pullTimeout` which is set to 15s on the default subscriber (when no explicit factory is defined):

```
pubSubSubscriberFactory = new DefaultPubSubSubscriberFactory(
    // subscriptionName
    ProjectSubscriptionName.format(projectName, subscriptionName),
    // retries
    3,
    // pullTimeout
    Duration.ofSeconds(15),
    // messagesPerPull
    100
);
```

You may want to consider defining a custom factory for your `PubSubSource` configuration to adjust these timeouts further via the `withPubSubSubscriberFactory()` function on the source:

```
PubSubSource.newBuilder()
    .withPubSubSubscriberFactory(...)
```

Per the source code, you may also want to ensure that the checkpointing frequency is **significantly** higher than your PubSub-related timeouts to avoid issues on that front:

> "The PubSubSource REQUIRES Checkpointing to be enabled and the checkpointing frequency must be MUCH lower than the PubSub timeout for it to retry a message."

You may want to consider increasing the `pullTimeout` to a larger value (such as 30s, 1m) while setting the checkpointing frequency so some percentage of that (half, quarter, etc.) to see if that helps resolve the timeouts.