# Flink Job consuming Google PubSub - DEADLINE_EXCEEDED exception

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming, google-cloud-pubsub, grpc-java

I'm running a POC in order to get messages from a topic on Google PubSub and process them in a Flink job.

After struggling for days, I was able to finally start getting the messages from PubSub using the PubSubSource from Flink.

Now I'm constantly getting one exception saying:

```bash
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: deadline exceeded after 14.999285491s. [remote_addr=pubsub.googleapis.com/142.250.125.95:443]
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:262)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:243)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:156)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.examples.gcp.pubsub.shaded.com.google.pubsub.v1.SubscriberGrpc$SubscriberBlockingStub.pull(SubscriberGrpc.java:1641)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.gcp.pubsub.BlockingGrpcPubSubSubscriber.pull(BlockingGrpcPubSubSubscriber.java:73)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.gcp.pubsub.BlockingGrpcPubSubSubscriber.pull(BlockingGrpcPubSubSubscriber.java:77)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.gcp.pubsub.BlockingGrpcPubSubSubscriber.pull(BlockingGrpcPubSubSubscriber.java:77)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.gcp.pubsub.BlockingGrpcPubSubSubscriber.pull(BlockingGrpcPubSubSubscriber.java:77)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.gcp.pubsub.BlockingGrpcPubSubSubscriber.pull(BlockingGrpcPubSubSubscriber.java:67)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.gcp.pubsub.PubSubSource.run(PubSubSource.java:128)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:110)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:67)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask$LegacySourceFunctionThread.run(SourceStreamTask.java:333)
```

...and my job keeps restarting.
I can see the messages but I don't know how to get rid of this exception.
It happen both locally and in the real Flink-cluster.

Has anybody faced something like this?
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting DEADLINE\_EXCEEDED on a Flink Job while using GCP PubSub source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77479904/getting-deadline-exceeded-on-a-flink-job-while-using-gcp-pubsub-source)